# display price without vat, tax and with VAT separately in cart page

Tags: magento2.3, price, vat

I need to display price without VAT, tax amount and price with VAT in cart page in this order

Answer (score 0):

Check in store -> configuration -> sales -> tax

Under Cart view settings there's some configs that display prices as you like,

[image]

Comment: Thank you, already tested but It did not display tax amount separately